# Get Windows CMD output using ActiveX

Tags: javascript, windows, cmd, activex, activexobject

I want to get the output of the CMD prompt in windows using ActiveX control.

When i use the following code:

```
var w = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");  
var ex =w.Exec('cmd /c dir /b');
var ret = ex.StdOut.ReadAll();
alert(ret);
```

The command **cmd /c dir /b** works fine and I get a list of files in the alert message.

But when I use a command like **cmd /c java -version** I get an empty message. I tried many variations of the above command but none seems to work.

Anyone with a clue?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but are you getting anything when running the said command in the cmd window manually?

Comment: @ Teemu yes, i get the java version

Comment: High level functions do streams. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/input-and-output-methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java -version` returns its output at the *StdErr* stream, so either do:

```java
var ret = ex.StdErr.ReadAll();
```

or do:

```java
var ex = w.Exec('cmd /C java -version 2>&1');
```

The `2>&1` part redirects the *StdErr* stream (`2`) to *StdOut* (`1`). See [this](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) for more information.